# Слухи ширятся(,) не ведая преград

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Слухи ширятся(,) не ведая преград.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Правильно:  *Слухи шИрятся, // **не ведая прегрАд**.*

Обособление сразу определяется по интонации (**два ударения**).

**По грамматике** мы видим, что ***ведать*** — переходный глагол, поэтому у нас всегда деепричастный оборот, а не **одиночное** деепричастие, которое  чаще не обособляется.

В Нацкорпусе   **[1](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj8qGAoICAEQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg/QvdC1INCy0LXQtNCw0Y8wAQ==) и  [2](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkwqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCKQonCiUKA3JlcRIeChzQvdC40YfQtdCz0L4g0L3QtSDQstC10LTQsNGPMAE=)**   оборот тоже обособлен.

2. Оборот имеет значение обстоятельства **образа действия**, поэтому теоретически его можно не обособить. Вероятно, возможен такой вариант:
   *Слухи ширятся / **прегрАд не ведая**.*

Сравнить: Слухи ширятся **без ограничений**. Здесь **одно ударение**, оно переходит со сказуемого на оборот.