# Надо(,) не скорбя(,) благословить

Tags: запятые

Нужна эта запятая в песне «У природы нет плохой погоды»? Она есть в тексте, но я думаю, что не нужна, т. к. здесь это деепричастие имеет значение 'бесскорбно'.

> Надо(,) не скорбя(,) благословить.

Comment: Если ударение ставится на деепричастном обороте, а значит, оборот будет частью сказуемого, то запятые не нужны. Если же эта не важная информация и обозначает какие-либо действия одновременно с благословением, то нужны. У Розенталя про действия одновременно с чем-то было записано.

Comment: (1) Деепричастие не может быть частью сказуемого, но может быть необособленным обстоятельством образа действия.  (2) Обособленное слово всегда выделено, но по разным мотивам (уточнение или актуализация). Здесь скорее второе.

Comment: Тогда деепричастие несов. вида обозначает действие, одновременное со сказуемым. Автор Эльдар Рязанов, фильм  "Служебный роман". https://rustih.ru/andrej-petrov-u-prirody-net-ploxoj-pogody/

Comment: При обособлении на деепричастие падает ударение... Вот только почему мы в комментариях отвечаем?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Много чего было сказано в комментариях, но при этом **суть решения** ясно  обозначена не была, а она такова.

Возможность двух вариантов определяется тем, что **структура** предложения допускает **оба прочтения**, то есть с обособлением и без него:

(1) *Надо, // **не скорбЯ**, //  **благословИть**.* Два ударения, на сказуемом и на деепричастии.

(2) *Надо  **не скорбЯ** **благословить.*** Одно ударение на деепричастии в роли **обстоятельства.**

Таким образом, автор не всегда может ставить знаки по **своему усмотрению** (важная или не очень важная информация), так как в некоторых  случаях структура предложения задает **однозначное** решение.
См. **[вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478477/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4)**